# (dart:mirrors) When reflecting a variable of type Function, no way to invoke

Tags: dart

Is there any way to invoke a function when the function itself is actually a variable?  I tried the following:

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

void main() {
  TestClass test = new TestClass();

  reflect(test).invoke(const Symbol("init"), []);
}

class TestClass {
  Function init = () => print("hi");
}
```

and ended up getting this error:

```
Breaking on exception: Class 'TestClass' has no instance method 'init'.

Exception: Class 'TestClass' has no instance method 'init'.

NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'init'
Receiver: Instance of 'TestClass'
Arguments: []
  main (http://127.0.0.1:3030/test/web/test.dart:6:23)
```

I see when reflecting this class that the "init" variable does show up in the declarations, however it's treated as a variable and not a function.  Just wondering if there's any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case init is a field/property that references a function.

remove the = and it works

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

void main() {
  TestClass test = new TestClass();

  var r =reflect(test).invoke(#init, []);
}

class TestClass {
  void init () => print("hi"); 
}
```

With your example you can invoke the closure like

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

void main() {
  TestClass test = new TestClass();

  ClosureMirror r = reflect(test.init);
  r.apply([]);
}

class TestClass {
  Function init = () => print("hi"); 
}
```

Extended example which checks if field or method

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

void main() {
  TestClass test = new TestClass();


  var m = reflectClass(TestClass).declarations[#init];

  if(m is VariableMirror) {
    (reflect(test.init) as ClosureMirror).apply([]);
  } else if (m is MethodMirror) {
    reflect(test).invoke(#init, []);
  }

  var m2 = reflectClass(TestClass).declarations[#init2];

  if(m is VariableMirror) {
    (reflect(test.init2) as ClosureMirror).apply([]);
  } else if (m is MethodMirror) {
    reflect(test).invoke(#init2, []);
  }
}

class TestClass {
  Function init = () => print("hi"); 
  void init2() => print("hi");
}
```

Comment: Well I understand that (I think), but I'm still not sure how to go about invoking the function reference...

edit: figured it out, posting under my main question in a sec

Comment: Ok, just saw your comment. I think my examle is slightly more elegant ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Think I answered my own question just now:

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

void main() {
  TestClass test = new TestClass();

  try {
    reflect(test).invoke(const Symbol("init"), []);
  } catch (e) {
    (reflect(test).getField(const Symbol("init")) as ClosureMirror).apply([]);
  }
}

class TestClass {
  Function init = () => print("hi");
}
```

That should do it, for anyone else wondering :-)

Comment: Ok, this is if you don't know if it's a method or a field that references a method.

Comment: Right, I probably should have been more specific.  This also lets you replace "init" with any function/method name.

Comment: A little more context is often helpful. Now that I understand what you want, your question looks perfecly fine to me ;-)

Comment: Note that you can call a function without going through mirrors at all, using Function.apply(test.init). However, in this example you still need the mirrors to get a member named by a string that's only known at runtime.